# How to grep, then search and replace on the output?

Tags: grep, replace, output

I have some output from iconv, e.g.

```
$ iconv -l | grep ISO | head -5
CSISO4UNITEDKINGDOM//
CSISO10SWEDISH//
CSISO11SWEDISHFORNAMES//
CSISO14JISC6220RO//
CSISO15ITALIAN//
durrantm:~
```

How can I change the `//`'s to, say `--`'s ?

I tried `$ (iconv -l | grep ISO).gsub('\/\/','--')` but no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few approaches using either `tr`, `awk` or `sed`

TR:

```
 iconv -l | grep ISO |head -5 |tr '/' '-'
```

AWK:

```
iconv -l | awk '/ISO/{gsub("//","--"); print $0}' |head -5
```

SED:

```
iconv -l | grep ISO |head -5 | sed 's/\//-/g'
# or, to avoid needing to escape the backslashes:
iconv -l | grep ISO |head -5 | sed 's#/#-#g'
```

Comment: For `tr` you can say `tr '/' '-'`. Global substitution is implied.

Comment: Updated this answer for TR to reflect that and also added my own sed option that avoids needing to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is an option:

```
$ iconv -l | grep ISO | sed 's#/#-#g' | head -5
CSISO4UNITEDKINGDOM--
CSISO10SWEDISH--
CSISO11SWEDISHFORNAMES--
CSISO14JISC6220RO--
CSISO15ITALIAN--
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is more or less a subset of `sed` (`grep` stands for the `g/re/p` command in `ed`, and `sed` is like `ed` applied to [s]treams), so you generally don't need to pipe them together.

```
iconv -l | sed '/ISO/!d;s,//,--,g' | head -n 5
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `sed` you don't have to use forward slashes to denote the arguments to search/replace. You can change them to anything you want. For example:

```
$ iconv -l|grep ISO | sed 's@//@--@g' | head -5
CSISO4UNITEDKINGDOM--
CSISO10SWEDISH--
CSISO11SWEDISHFORNAMES--
CSISO14JISC6220RO--
CSISO15ITALIAN--
```

This can be condensed since you're looking for the same character to this:

```
$ iconv -l|grep ISO|sed 's@/@-@g' | head -5
CSISO4UNITEDKINGDOM--
CSISO10SWEDISH--
CSISO11SWEDISHFORNAMES--
CSISO14JISC6220RO--
CSISO15ITALIAN--
```

Comment: No need for `//` and `--` since you're using global substitution.

Comment: @JosephR. - yeah I was getting to it. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, but I'd use `sed` with the `-n` aka `--quiet` or `--silent` option to suppress output by default.

```
iconv -l | sed -n -e '/ISO/ s://:--:p'
```

That sed script ignores lines not containing "ISO", changes // to --, and prints the (modified) matching line.  The final 'p' in the script is what tells sed to print that matching line.

To avoid lots of ugly backslash-escaping, I've used `:` as the regexp separator character rather than `/`

See the sed man page for more details.